# is there any plausible scenario in which a programmer might wish to avoid shortcircuit evaluation of a Boolean expression?

Tags: c++, c, short-circuiting

short circuit evaluation can shorten the compile time, so i learned that C, C++ is using that way. But are there any situations that short-circuit evaluation ruining the code?

Comment: short-circuit evaluation is a language feature. So writing code that depended on it not working would not be expressing intend correctly.

Comment: Shortening the compile time seems unlikely unless either condition is statically constant. Perhaps shortening the runtime?

Comment: 'short circuit evaluation can shorten the compile time' no, not significantly.  That is not why it is used.

Comment: More important is that short-circuiting conveniently allows writing *correct* code, such as `if (p != nullptr && p->value != 25)`; this code would have undefined behaviour if both operands were evaluated.

Comment: You can easily make up and test examples where a short-circuited expression that is not evaluated, but would have a side-effect which is subsequently used, has the wrong value.

Comment: Sure, poorly predicted branches are very expensive.  So if the left operand expression is random and there is no good reason to avoid evaluating the right operand then you can be significantly ahead.  Try it, measure if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') on random text, using both && and & to see what your compiler can do.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I'm a novice using c language.
I am confusing about && and &.
I learned that && literally means 'and', & is a bitwise operation.
and if I code like (ch>='A' & ch <='Z'), I wonder 1. can I compare the scale of  strings? 2. can I do bitwise operation on the expression "ch>='A'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short circuiting does not shorten the compile time of the code. (by any meaningful amounts, at least)

It might be shortening the runtime, but it's not its intended purpose.

The purpose of short circuiting is to do the minimal amount of work in order to check a certain condition.

For example:

When using `&&` (as opposed to a single `&`), the right operand won't be evaluated if the left one is false. This is due to the nature of a `logical and` operation: if at least one of the operands is false, the whole expression is false.

Technically, it will shorten the runtime if the condition fails early, but the amount of saved runtime is dependent on the expressions inside each operand.

Anyway, it's incorrect to use `&&` because it's "faster" than `&`. You should use either when appropriate.

`&` is used for bitwise operations.